# Выделение топовых мест в angular js

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день. Хотел узнать , можно ли в ангулар сделать выделение 1-2-3 мест в таблице? (Допустим размером шрифта. )
Не знаю нужно создавать ли отдельный вопрос , но мне нужно еще сделать в этой таблице автоматическое добавление столбика с номером строки.

```js
  var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
  CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cups = [
      {user: 'user1', Total: 1},
      {user: 'user2', Total: 2},
      {user: 'user3', Total: 3},
      {user: 'user4', Total: 4},
      {user: 'user5', Total: 5},
      {user: 'user6', Total: 6}
    ];
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="CupApp" ng-controller="CupCtrl">
  <div id="container">

    <div id="Html1">
      <h2>Топ в компании</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Менеджер</th>
          <th>Балы</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-Total' ">
          <td>{{cup.user}}</td>
          <td>{{cup.Total}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот сам код вывода таблицы

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <tr>
    <th>Менеджер</th>
    <th>Балы</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-Total' ">
    <td>{{cup.user}}</td>
    <td>{{cup.Total}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: отформатируй вопрос так, чтобы убралось лишнее. Ни список, ни картинки судя по всему не нужны, код в конце вопроса - непонятно что за кусок и почему после скрипта еще неполный кусок html

Comment: Код изменил , не то вставил извините. А по поводу вопроса не понимаю , вроде бы указал все понятно , не могли бы подробнее сказать что не так в вопросе.

Comment: Например,  `<td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '24pt'} : ''">{{cup.user}}</td>`. А лучше аналогично, но через `ng-class`.

Comment: Спасибо помогло! А как сделать дополнительно столбик с нумерацией не подскажите?

Comment: `<td>{{ $index }}</td>` например так

Comment: только нумерация $index с 0

Comment: @Yaant, почему не ответом? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Потому что комментарием можно одной строчкой дать идею, а вот полноценный ответ надо бы расписать подробнее. А мне в данный момент лень, да и немного некогда. :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!   
"только нумерация $index с 0" а с 1 можно сделать?

Comment: Вот так попробуйте <td>{{ $index + 1}}</td>

Comment: Да , работает. Спасибо огромное.